# Mod_rewrite - how to 301 redirect an old URL to a new one

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, isapi-rewrite

I need to grab some of my website's old URLs and do a 301 redirect to the new ones, since they are already indexed and we don't want to loose relevance after the change. The old URL is in fact very ugly and for some reason everything I try to do to rewrite it does not work. Here it is:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/ExibeCurso.asp?Comando=TreinamentoGeral&codCurso=136&Titulo=Como%20Estruturar%20um%20Sistema%20Gerencial%20de%20Controles%20Organizacionais,13
```

Basically, I need to translate it into something like:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/curso/136
```

From the old URL I need to check if the user typed "ExibeCurso.asp"; then I know I must send him here: /curso. I must also grab the integer that was in the querystring parameter "codCurso" (136). What is the regular expression I must use for this. I am using ISAPI_Rewrite 3, which basically implements htaccess on IIS, so there should be no difference in terms of syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*codCurso=([0-9]+)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/ExibeCurso\.asp$ /curso/%2? [L,R=301]
```

But I’m not sure whether ISAPI Rewrite requires the pattern to begin with a slash.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I managed to solve the problem before seeing your post and it was very much like your answer. Thanks a lot! By the way, I am always confused with RegEx. What is this doing ([^&]*&)*? Telling the system to pick anything but a & and then getting the & before the codCurso querystring param? Thanks.

Comment: hum, I think ISAPI Rewrite works exactly like this... Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, something like this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^ExibeCurso.asp(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/curso/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That would at least send the traffic to /curso/ with all parameters attached. Maybe it's best to process it from there.